# How i can use multiple textdomain in php gettext?

Tags: php, gettext

I want to load multiple mo files in gettext at the same time

An example:

```
$lang = 'en_US';

putenv('LC_ALL=' . $lang);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);

bindtextdomain('module', ROOT . 'Language');
bindtextdomain('default', ROOT . 'Language');

textdomain('module');
textdomain('default');
```

But I can not use two "textdomains" at the same time. This code gives only one language. I want to use multiple "bindtextdomain" and .mo files at the same time.

I have many modules. Each module must be have separate "mo" files. And each module loads at the same files.

How i can use multiple textdomain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have need two function. First function is dynamically change gettext domain.
Second function is working like default gettext method.
Briefly; You must change gettext domain and select domain in a function.

```
function selectDomain($trFile)
{
    if ($trFile == 'default') {
        bindtextdomain($trFile, ROOT . 'Language');
    } else {
        bindtextdomain($trFile, MROOT . $trFile . '/Language');
    }

    textdomain($trFile);
}


function _e($msgid, $trFile = 'default')
{
    selectDomain($trFile);
    return _($msgid);
}

echo _e('Test');
echo _e('Test','another_text_domain');
```